# I'm not able to get selected year from date picker in android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm using a date picker in my code for selecting date of birth. I'm getting selected day and month but facing problem in fetching year. I want date in **MM/dd/yyyy** format.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
final DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(getActivity());
picker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
final Calendar c =Calendar.getInstance();

picker.setMaxDate(c.getTime().getTime());
builder.setView(picker)
        .setPositiveButton("UPDATE",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                picker.setMaxDate(c.getTime().getTime());
                final SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                final Date d=new Date();
                d.setYear(picker.getYear());d.setMonth(picker.getMonth());d.setDate(picker.getDayOfMonth());
                String s=sdf.format(d);
                dob.setText(s);
                Log.e("DOB",s);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .create()
        .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) directly:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), onDateListener, year, month, day);
```

Comment: thanx for the response. It's not like that i'm not getting date. but i'm getting garbage value in year section such as : if i choose **24 Aug 2012** it shows **8/24/3912** and its always 39 in the starting of year

Comment: Could be something related to `setMaxDate`? Some time ago I had some problems with `setMinDate` as I was using something like `setMinDate(new Date().getTime())` and it couldn't handle that right now was the minimum date. It was solved by using `setMinDate(new Date().getTime() - 1000)`. Try changing `picker.setMaxDate(c.getTime().getTime());` for `picker.setMaxDate(c.getTime().getTime() + 1000);`

Comment: thank you for the response . I'v resolved the problem by appending individual date month and year